# C++ How to declare my array and other integers in a different cpp file from where they are filled?

Tags: c++, object, scope

So heres what im trying to do with my text based rpg now. I want to clean up my `main.cpp` so that it isnt so long and cluttered, so I am creating a few different cpp files that will hold related items.

I have a `maketoon.cpp` file that will go through some switch statements that will set all the modifiers(str, int, agl, maxhp) based on the class they choose(class being like lumberjack doctor etc not classes in the object sense of things).

when setting the variables in the maketoon.cpp(within a function called `makeMainPlayer()` ) i use setters that i made within my `createcharacter.h` file.

So before you look at my code below, i have a few questions.

1)Where should i create the object(`main.cpp`, `maketoon.cpp`).  Currently i was creating the object `Player` in the maketoon.cpp file but im getting these errors:

```
||=== Build: Debug in 6_days_to_escape (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\...\maketoon.cpp||In function 'int makeMainPlayer()':|
C:\...\maketoon.cpp|5|error: 'startChoices' was not declared in this scope|
C:\...\maketoon.cpp|6|error: 'name' was not declared in this scope|
C:\...\main.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
C:\...\main.cpp|39|error: 'Player' was not declared in this scope|
||=== Build failed: 3 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

2)Should i capitalize the first letting in my object name?
3)how do i call makeMainPlayer in my main.cpp so set that specific objects values to then start the game?
4)Lastly, when i was testing to see if the setters and getters were working, i was getting another `Player not declared in this scope` error, so i tried just banging out another `CreateCharacter Player;`at the start of my int main, but i feel that will overwrite all the values set in the later functions, with the default null values.

Also. I know nothing about pointers, but if that is the best way to go(some google searches popped up with this as a fix to similar scenarios)

Seriosly thanks a ton! Im trying to teach myself OOc++ and it is proving difficult. Getting lost in the online tuts and youtube tuts.

```
    //main.cpp
    //game rpg
    #include <iostream>
    #include <ctime>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include "createcharacter.h"
    #include "maketoon.cpp"

    using namespace std;

    //is running check
    bool running = 1;

    //int healedHP(int x, int y);
    //int attackedHP(int x, int y);

    //user input var+
    int userInput = 0;
    int startChoices[4] = {0, 0, 0, 0};
    string name;
    //function declarations
    void theStart();
    void newGame();



    int main (){
        void makeMainPlayer();
        cout << "Enter your name." << endl;
        cin >> name;
        cout << "Welcome " << name << "." << endl;
        cout << "Strike any key....if you dare......";
        getch();
        system("cls");

        theStart();
        makeMainPlayer();

        cout << "Name: " << Player.getplayerName() << endl;
        cout << "Health: " << Player.getplayerHealth() << endl;
        cout << "Strength: " << Player.getStr() << endl;
        cout << "Int: " << Player.getInt() << endl;
        cout << "Agility: " << Player.getAgl() << endl;
        cout << "Difficulty: " << Player.getDifficulty() << endl;


        system("pause");
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    void theStart()
    {
        cout << "\n\n";
        cout << "\t6 Days to Escape!\n"; //title
        cout << "\t\t  1: Play\n"; //main menu options. The first thing the user sees.
        cout << "\t\t\t  2: Exit\n";
        cin >> userInput;
        system("cls");
        if(userInput == 1)
        {
            // Create a new game
            newGame();
        }
        else
        {
            //bool then false causeing program to exit
            running = 0;
        }

        return;
    }
    void newGame(){
        // there are 4 addresses in this array for the following:
        //0. Difficulty
        //1. Class
        //2. Starting Wep
        //3. Boost not implimented yet TODO
        //enum class difficulty{simple, easy, hard, impossible};
        do{
            cout << "Choose Your difficulty: " << endl;
            cout << "\t1. Simple - Game practically plays itself." << endl;
            cout << "\t2. Easy - Not that easy." << endl;
            cout << "\t3. Hard - Zombies do more than crave flesh." << endl;
            cout << "\t4. Impossible - You will not make it." << endl;
            cin >> startChoices[0];
            cout << endl;
            system("cls");
            if(startChoices[0] < 1 || startChoices[0] > 4){
                cout << "Invalid Difficulty Choice. Try again." << endl;}
        }while(startChoices[0] < 1 || startChoices[0] > 4);

        do{
            cout << "Choose your class:" << endl;
            cout << "\t1. Lumber Jack - Stong, hard to kill, but slow." << endl;
            cout << "\t2. Doctor - Healer, weak but fast. Favors health." << endl;
            cout << "\t3. Theif - FAST, Cunning but weak attacks." << endl;
            cout << "\t4. Everydayer - Balenced everything." << endl;
            cin >> startChoices[1];
            cout << endl;
            system("cls");
            if(startChoices[1] < 1 || startChoices[1] > 4){
                cout << "Invalid Class Choice. Try again." << endl;}
        }while(startChoices[1] < 1 || startChoices[1] > 4);

        do{
            cout << "Choose your starting Weapon:" << endl;
            cout << "\t1. Axe" << endl;
            cout << "\t2. Crowbar" << endl;
            cout << "\t3. Swiss army knife" << endl;
            cout << "\t4. Ice pick" << endl;
            cin >> startChoices[2];
            cout << endl;
            if(startChoices[0] < 1 || startChoices[0] > 4){
                cout << "Invalid Weapon Choice. Try again." << endl;}
        }while(startChoices[2] < 1 || startChoices[2] > 4);

        }

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //createcharacter.h
    #ifndef CREATECHARACTER_H
        #define CREATECHARACTER_H
        class CreateCharacter{
            public:
                //setter
                void setplayerName(std::string x){
                    playerName = x;}
                void setwepSpeed(int v){
                    wepSpeed = v;}
                void setplayerHealth(int h){
                    playerHealth = h;}
                void setplayerMaxHealth(int mh){
                    playerMaxHealth = mh;}
                void setplayerStr(int s){
                    playerStr = s;}
                void setplayerAgl(int a){
                    playerAgl = a;}
                void setplayerInt(int i){
                    playerInt = i;}
                void setplayerDifficulty(int d){
                    playerDifficulty = d;}
                void setwepbaseDmg(int j){
                    wepbaseDmg = j;}

                //getters
                std::string getplayerName(){
                    return playerName;}
                int getplayerHealth(){
                    return playerHealth;}
                int getMaxHealth(){
                    return playerMaxHealth;}
                int getStr(){
                    return playerStr;}
                int getAgl(){
                    return playerAgl;}
                int getInt(){
                    return playerInt;}
                int getDifficulty(){
                    return playerDifficulty;}



            private:
                std::string playerName;
                int playerHealth;
                int playerMaxHealth; //absolute max = 200
                int playerStr; // absolute max = 20
                int playerAgl;// absolute max = 20
                int playerInt;// absolute max = 20
                int playerDifficulty; // absolute max = 4
                //items
                int wepbaseDmg;
                int wepSpeed;
        };

        #endif

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//maketoon.cpp
//This was my attempt based off google....
//int* startChoices[4]={getDifficulty(), get};
int makeMainPlayer(){
    CreateCharacter Player;
    Player.setplayerDifficulty(startChoices[0]);
    Player.setplayerName(name);

    switch(startChoices[1]){
        case 1:
            Player.setplayerMaxHealth(175);
            Player.setplayerStr(18);
            Player.setplayerAgl(10);
            Player.setplayerInt(6);
            break;
        case 2:
            Player.setplayerMaxHealth(200);
            Player.setplayerStr(9);
            Player.setplayerAgl(13);
            Player.setplayerInt(15);
            break;
        case 3:
            Player.setplayerMaxHealth(100);
            Player.setplayerStr(11);
            Player.setplayerAgl(20);
            Player.setplayerInt(10);
            break;
        case 4:
            Player.setplayerMaxHealth(150);
            Player.setplayerStr(12);
            Player.setplayerAgl(12);
            Player.setplayerInt(13);
            break;
    }
    switch(startChoices[2]){
        case 1:
            Player.setwepbaseDmg(40);
            Player.setwepSpeed(4);
            break;
        case 2:
            Player.setwepbaseDmg(30);
            Player.setwepSpeed(5);
            break;
        case 3:
            Player.setwepbaseDmg(25);
            Player.setwepSpeed(8);
            break;
        case 4:
            Player.setwepbaseDmg(20);
            Player.setwepSpeed(10);
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int main (){ void makeMainPlayer();` What?

Comment: `#include "maketoon.cpp"` Never include a cpp file.

Comment: `int makeMainPlayer(){ CreateCharacter Player;` Player is a local variable in makeMainPlayer. It will no longer exist when makeMainPlayer() returns.

Comment: `error: 'startChoices' was not declared in this scope` - the simplest and best fix is to pass the arguments like `startChoices` and `name` to the functions that want to use them as by-reference function arguments, then move the combined declaration/definition for each of those into `main()`.  2) it's debatable - personally I prefer to capitalise class names.

Comment: Hmm ok. SO i get the passing of the variables via the function arguments.  But my next question is 'int makeMainPlayer(){CreateCharacter Player;}` If i just create that object at the start of my main function can i use that object all over the place then? I mainly want to have a running oject that is storing all of the info that the player has (like halth, strength eventually items) and then also be able to use certain parts of the class to also make monsters(like just hp and dmg.).  does that make sense?  Thanks for the help!!